# Ordering and then setting variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have the following code which orders my data in mysql perfectly:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
mysql_select_db("users");

$pop = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY pop DESC LIMIT 9

");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pop))
    {
    echo $row['imagefile'];
    echo "<br />";
    }




mysql_close($con);



?>
```

However i would like for each "result" to then automatically be assigned as a variable.  So for example "uploads/logo.png" comes out as the first "result" of the above code.  I would then want this to be assigned $image_1 - so in code it would read $image_1 = "uploads/logo.png".  I then want all the other 8 outputs to be assigned to variables so that $image_2 corresponds to the second output and so on.  This is only a prototype.  I wish for it to eventually output 100 results.  Is this at all possible?  Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You should look into PDO for secure database transactions. mysql_* functions are going to be deprecated soon. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: i dont understand nothing what u want or what u have in database , can u explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array.

```
$images = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pop))
    $images[] = $row['imagefile'];
```

Or keep the associative array:

```
$imageData = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pop))
    $imageData[] = $row;

// $imageData[0]['imageFile'] will be "uploads/logo.png"
```

---

Edit for comment below:

First method from above:

```
<?php
foreach ($images as $image) {

    echo <<<EOT
<div class="box"><img src= "$image" width="200" height="150"></a></div>
EOT;
}
?>
```

Second method could be more involved, depending on your data:

```
<?php
foreach ($imageData as $image) {
    $imagePath = $image['imageFile'];
    $imageWidth = $image['width'];
    $imageHeight = $image['height'];
    echo <<<HTML
<div class="box"><img src= "$imagePath" width=$imageWidth height=$imageHeight></a></div>
HTML;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Does that mean $image1 = "uploads/logo.png" or $image_1?  Only i am now having trouble getting the image variable to display in the browser.  I have...

Comment: <div class="box"><img src= "<?php echo $image1; ?>" width="200" height="150"></a></div>

Comment: Right i'm not familiar with the "EOT" and "foreach" bits of php.  Do i just insert that into my php script and then it will work for the html script below where i simply put "$image" in each img src?  I have a hundred boxes you see and want the images displayed within to be in accordance with the ordering sort.

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way for your help

Comment: The <<< signifies the start of text, followed by some characters that will indicate the End Of Text.  I changed the second example to show a variation with HTML marking the begin and end of text.  This allows you to have double or single quotes without escaping them.  Notice that when you use this or double quotes, php variable names in the string literal mean "pass the value of this variable", whereas in single quote string literals it takes the variable name as a part of the string literal.

Comment: foreach iterates through the array, as explained in the documentation: [php docs foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: thank you very much.  Turns out your very first answer did the job.  I stupidly copied it as "$image = array ()" rather than "$image".